# public facing full node with nginx

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, nodes

I am running a node on a Hosted root server, and will soon be synced, but I am not sure how I can now use this node to mine with my local Unix miner.

**What I have**

- Xenon CPU with 32GB RAM
- 1 Terrabyte HDD
- 10 MBit Internet Connection
- Ubuntu 16
- geth 1.7.3-stable
- FQDN

Compared to my [lame home node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/geth-keeps-failing-to-sync-past-a-certain-point) this puppy is blazing through the blockchain syncing and could be done real soon. (Caution: keep your peers low)

Now in theory I need to open a incoming port on my firewall to the node for my home miner, setup the node to only accept miner connection from my IP-range, and then I should be set. (Hallo iptables)

Can anybody help me get the geth setup right?

I start my node with:

```
geth --identity TheNewNodeName --cache=2048 --maxpeers 12 --rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost --rpcapi debug,personal,eth,web3,miner console 2>&1 | tee /tmp/eth.log
```

I have also tried changing the values for --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*"

I have setup a nginx proxy on a sub-domain with a high port number that then forwards to the localhost 8545, but it seems I am missing some more ports as the initial contact gets through (according to the miner and the target iptraf) but the miner then just says 
`stratum Discarding incomplete response`
and iptraf reports a new request on the same incoming port but a different TCP outgoing port...?

nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen sub.domain.tld:14949;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8545;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
  }
}
```